# Stroke text attributes for title in navigation bar are not applied

Tags: ios, swift

I can't figure out why the same stroke text attributes look different for navigation bar title and text label. I would like the title to look like the label, please advise:

```
    let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 30))
    let strokeTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.init(name:
        "Helvetica-Bold", size:20.0),
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.black,
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
                                NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -3.0,
                                ] as [String : Any]

    myLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Test", attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = strokeTextAttributes
    self.title = "Test"
    self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
```

[image]

Comment: Other examples suggest you need to set `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes` (which probably needs conversion to Swift 3 if that's what you're using)

Comment: hmm, didn't help, title became black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using titleView property of navigationItem like this:

```
let strokeTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.init(name:
                        "Helvetica-Bold", size:20.0),
                                            NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue,
                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
                                            NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -3.0,
                                            ] as [String : Any]
                let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 30))


                myLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Test", attributes: strokeTextAttributes)

                navigationItem.titleView = myLabel
```